# How to use OpenCV build (opencv and opencv_contrib) in a Maven project

Tags: java, opencv, jar, m2eclipse

I compiled openCV and OpenCV_contrib library and had the resulting `build/bin/opencv-411.jar` and libraries .so in `build/lib/`. Now I am wondering how can I add these to my Maven project?

I was using that [Maven repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openpnp/opencv/3.4.2-1/) but the contrib modules are not available.

I tried including the jar as a dependency like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22300875/11140715) with:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv-411</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version> 
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${resourcesfolder}/opencv-411.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I get no error when I launch `clean javafx:compile` but when I launch `clean javafx:run` a lot of OpenCV errors appear :

**[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :**

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/.../src/main/java/model/VideoModel.java:[3,23] package org.opencv.core does not exist
[ERROR] /home/.../src/main/java/model/VideoModel.java:[4,23] package org.opencv.core does not exist
[ERROR] /home/.../src/main/java/model/VideoModel.java:[5,26] package org.opencv.videoio does not exist
[ERROR] /home/.../src/main/java/model/VideoModel.java:[6,26] package org.opencv.videoio does not exist
[ERROR] /home/.../src/main/java/model/VideoModel.java:[25,17] cannot find symbol
     symbol:   class VideoCapture
     location: class model.VideoModel
[ERROR] /home/.../src/main/java/model/VideoModel.java:[26,17] cannot find symbol
     symbol:   class Mat
```

I also had a look to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220467/11140715) but he deployed his new jar containing the executables and libraries in a remote repository. The interesting part is the jar creation, so I tried to do the same with `opencv-411.jar` and `lib/` folder with:

```sh
cp opencv-411.jar opencv-411-new.jar
jar -uvf opencv-411-new.jar lib/
```

and kept the dependency as above, but raised the same errors...

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the answers, I came to the solution for including OpenCV jar and libs to Maven:

- install the jar in the maven local repository with:

```sh
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/.../src/main/resources/opencv.jar -DgroupId=org -DartifactId=opencv -Dversion=4.1.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

- create the dependency in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency> 
 <groupId>org</groupId> 
 <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
 <version>4.1.1</version>  
</dependency>
```

Now that the jar is included, we must add the OpenCV libraries somehow.

Just load the library in your app with:

```java
System.load("/path/to/lib/libopencv_java411.so");
```

For the UI tests, as the maven-surefire-plugin uses a special JVM, you have to specify the lib folder to the java.library.path:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.22.2</version>
 <configuration>
  <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${project.build.outputDirectory}/lib</argLine>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please feel free to edit if you have a better solution or corrections to add.

Answer (score 0):

Maven expects the artifacts (.jar files, etc.) in $USER_HOME/.m2 since you compiled opencv yourself you also need to install the file (as 3rd party module) in the local maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Where the variables need to match those you use in you pom.xml and packaging must be set to `jar`.

See also: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I did the command `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/.../src/main/resources/opencv.jar -DgroupId=org   -DartifactId=opencv -Dversion=4.1.1 -Dpackaging=jar` and removed scope and systemPath from the dependency. But I get "Error: Could not find or load main class" from javafx-maven-plugin, it was working before..

Comment: In your pom snippet you're refering to version 4.1.0 (not 4.1.1) you could try mvn -x (for more detailed output)

Comment: The version was also modified so it is not the problem. I added the OpenCV library path to java.lib.path with `<argLine>-Djava.library.path=/home/.../target/classes/lib</argLine>` to maven-surefire-plugin and the `clean package` maven goals worked (launched every test)! But the `clean javafx:run` still throw the "Could not find or load main class ..."

Answer (score 0):

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\your jar path -DgroupId=org.opencv -DartifactId=opencv-411 -Dversion=4.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
you can use this one may be solve your issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did that command, changed the dependency and added the OpenCV libs path to maven-surefire-plugin. The `package` goal works perfectly, but the `javafx:run` does not work because it doesn't find the main class..